# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './undefined'

Tags: reactjs

I watched the code multiple times to figure out the problem but couldn't find the solution to this exception thrown at the console. The Product page blanks out.

**Product.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Navbar from '../../Components/Navbar/Navbar'
import Announcment from '../../Components/Announcment/Announcment'
import Newsletter from '../../Components/Newsletter/Newsletter'
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import './Product.css'
import { Add, Remove } from '@mui/icons-material'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import {publicRequest} from '../../requestMethod';
const Container = styled.div`

`
const Wrapper = styled.div`
padding: 50px;
display: flex;
`
const ImageContainer = styled.div`
flex: 1;
`
const InfoContainer = styled.div`
flex: 1;
padding: 0 50px;
`
const Title = styled.h1`
font-weight: 200;

`
const Desc = styled.p`
margin: 20px 0;
`
const Price = styled.span`
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 40px;
`
const FilterContainer = styled.div`
width: 50%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
margin: 30px 0;
`
const Filter = styled.div`
display: flex;
align-items: center;
`
const FilterTitle = styled.span`
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 200;
`
const FilterColor = styled.div`
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: ${props => props.color};
margin: 0 5px;
cursor: pointer;
`
const FilterSize = styled.select`
margin-left: 10px;
padding: 5px;
`
const FilterSizeOption = styled.option`

`
const AddContainer = styled.div`
width: 50%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
`
const AmountContainer = styled.div`
display: flex;
align-items: center;
font-weight: 700;

`
const Amount = styled.span`
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 1px solid teal;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin: 0 5px;
`
const Button = styled.button`
padding: 15px;
border: 3px solid teal;
background-color: white;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: 500;
&:hover{
    background-color: #f8f4f4;
}
`;

const Product = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const Id = location.pathname.split('/')[2];
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        const getSingleProduct = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await publicRequest.get(`/products/find/${Id}`);
                setProduct(res.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        getSingleProduct();
    }, [Id]);

    return (
        <Container>
            <Navbar />
            <Announcment />
            <Wrapper>
                <ImageContainer>
                    <img src={require(`../../Assets/${product.img}`)} alt='' className='productImg2' />
                </ImageContainer>
                <InfoContainer>
                    <Title>{product.title}</Title>
                    <Desc>{product.desc}</Desc>
                    <Price>$ {product.price}</Price>
                    <FilterContainer>
                        <Filter>
                            <FilterTitle>Color</FilterTitle>
                            {product.color.map((c, i) => (
                                <React.Fragment key={i}>
                                    <FilterColor color={c} />
                                </React.Fragment>
                            ))
                            }
                        </Filter>
                        <Filter>
                            <FilterTitle>Size</FilterTitle>
                            <FilterSize>
                                {product.size.map((s, i) => (
                                    <React.Fragment key={i}>
                                        <FilterSizeOption>{s}</FilterSizeOption>
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                ))
                                }

                            </FilterSize>
                        </Filter>
                    </FilterContainer>
                    <AddContainer>
                        <AmountContainer>
                            <Remove style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} />
                            <Amount>1</Amount>
                            <Add style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} />
                        </AmountContainer>
                        <Button>ADD TO CART</Button>
                    </AddContainer>
                </InfoContainer>
            </Wrapper>
            <Newsletter />
            <Footer />
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Product
```

**requestMethod.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api";
const Token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYyZjI5NmRjY2JmYzNjZTAyNGRhODNlNSIsImlzQWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTY2MDEzMzExNiwiZXhwIjoxNjYwMzkyMzE2fQ.TMBcTYhOKhsGTqHgVY6fAGoX9UCc2rC100JwvzoSqhE";

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL:BASE_URL,
});
export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL:BASE_URL,
    headers:{token:`Bearer ${Token}`},
});
```

**error**
.*$:106 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './undefined'
at webpackContextResolve (.*$:106:1)
at webpackContext (.*$:101:1)
at Product (Product.jsx:120:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)

The above error occurred in the  component:

```
at Product (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3288:81)
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56686:5)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56619:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55428:5)
at App
```

Comment: Your component renders with an empty `product`. Then, much later, your ajax request finishes, and sets the product. Your component needs to handle the loading case.

Answer (score 0):

First time try to check if the product object it's not empty.

Or try every property with product?.title, product?.desc and so on

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved by doing these changes.

```
const Product = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const Id = location.pathname.split('/')[2];
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        const getSingleProduct = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await publicRequest.get(`/products/find/${Id}`);
                setProduct(res.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        getSingleProduct();
    }, [Id]);
    return (
        <Container>
            <Navbar />
            <Announcment />
            <Wrapper>
                <ImageContainer>
                    <img src={product?.img ? require(`../../Assets/${product.img}`) : require('../../Assets/gray-men-shoes-1-free-img.jpg')} alt='' className='productImg2' />
                </ImageContainer>
                <InfoContainer>
                    <Title>{product?.title ? product.title : "Gray shoes"}</Title>
                    <Desc>{product?.desc ? product.desc : "abc"}</Desc>
                    <Price>$ {product?.price ? product.price : 20}</Price>
                    <FilterContainer>
                        <Filter>
                            <FilterTitle>Color</FilterTitle>
                            {product.color ? product.color.map((c, i) => (
                                <FilterColor color={c} key={i} />
                            ))
                                : <><FilterColor color="black" /></>
                            }
                        </Filter>
                        <Filter>
                            <FilterTitle>Size</FilterTitle>
                            <FilterSize>
                                {product.size ? product.size.map((s, i) => (
                                    <FilterSizeOption key={i}>{s}</FilterSizeOption>
                                ))
                                    : <> <FilterSizeOption >small</FilterSizeOption></>
                                }
                            </FilterSize>
                        </Filter>
                    </FilterContainer>
                    <AddContainer>
                        <AmountContainer>
                            <Remove style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} />
                            <Amount>1</Amount>
                            <Add style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} />
                        </AmountContainer>
                        <Button>ADD TO CART</Button>
                    </AddContainer>
                </InfoContainer>
            </Wrapper>
            <Newsletter />
            <Footer />
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Product
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).